# Stacking Monads using Monads Transformers

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am learning Monad Transformers and I am trying to learn how to nest Monads.

So let's say I want to create a `Future[Either[String, Option[A]]]`

So in order to model this shape I did

```
type Error = String
type FutureEither = EitherT[Future, Error, A]
type FutureEitherOption = OptionT[FutureEither, A]
```

Now I do

```
val p1 = 1.pure[FutureEitherOption]
```

and I get

```
OptionT(EitherT(Future(Success(Right(Some(1))))))
```

So this looks correct. I have a 1 inside of an Option which is inside of a Right, Which is inside of a Future Success. Good!

But If I do

```
Option.empty[Int].pure[FutureEitherOption]
```

I was hoping that I will get `Future(Success(Right(None)))` but I see output

```
OptionT(EitherT(Future(Success(Right(Some(None))))))
```

Also, If I want something like

```
Future(Success(Left("fail")))
```

If i try to do

```
val p2 = Left("fail").pure[FutureEitherOption]
```

The output is weird

```
OptionT(EitherT(Future(Success(Right(Some(Left(fail)))))))
```

That's not my shape at all because now there are two Eithers....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1` is of type `Int` and so by calling `.pure[FutureEitherOption]` you get the right shape:

```scala
OptionT(EitherT(Success(Right(Some(1)))))
```

`Option.empty[Int]` is of type `Option[Int]` so you need to do:

```scala
OptionT[FutureEither, Int](Option.empty[Int].pure[FutureEither])
```

in order to get the the right shape:

```scala
OptionT(EitherT(Success(Right(None))))
```

`Left("fail")` is of type `Left[String, Nothing]` (but actually also `Either[Error, Option[Int]]`) so you need to do:

```scala
OptionT[FutureEither, Int](EitherT[Future, Error, Option[Int]](Either.left[Error, Option[Int]]("fail").pure[Future]))
```

in order to get the the right shape:

```scala
OptionT(EitherT(Success(Left(fail))))
```

Then you can finally compose all of those. For example you can write a for-comprehension as:

```scala
for {
  a <- 1.pure[FutureEitherOption]
  b <- OptionT[FutureEither, Int](Option.empty[Int].pure[FutureEither])
  c <- OptionT[FutureEither, Int](EitherT[Future, Error, Option[Int]](Either.left[Error, Option[Int]]("fail").pure[Future]))
} yield ()
```

Note: I have explicitly annotated all types in order to let you better understand what its going on.